# MongoDB connections on require or by function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am working on a single pager that writes to different mongodb databases through an API setup with express. To do this I have one file named db.js that is doing all of the work with the mongoose module and then exporting the two connections to my express file called app.js.

When I start running my app file with node, my mongo console shows the two connections being made.

My question is, should I be making the exports structured so that they are functions that only connect to the DB when the functions themselves are called? Is there anything bad about leaving the two connections open and waiting for people to use them?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have your database connections created on start of the application, and leaving them open. The other way to create connections when an API call is made is extremely inefficient, because the connection load increases wrt number of API calls, and also because the response time of the API increases.

In db.js export your objects.
In your app.js, you can directly require the appropriate connection and start using it

```
var db = require("../db").first;

db.find({}, function (err, res) {})
```

Comment: that's basically what I'm doing at the moment in your example. Do you have anywhere I can read about the efficiency/reliability of keeping the connections open vs. opening them when needed?